# Search through the content of a pdf file with objective-c or jquery mobile

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, pdf, jquery-mobile

I've made an app which lists 16 pdf files, they are packed in the application.
I need a search function which not only searches on the title of the pdf's but also in the content of the pdf.

Is this possible with objective-c/ios or preferably with jquery mobile?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [pspdfkit](http://pspdfkit.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that using jQuery mobile. You can use a library like [pspdfkit](http://pspdfkit.com/) for achieving this using iOS/objective-c